# $\frac{dy}{dx}$ Vs. $\dfrac{1}{\frac{dx}{dy}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Today, my friend gave me a question which is stated below:

> On the curve $x^3 = 12y$, the abscissa changes at a faster rate than the ordinate. Then find the interval in which $x$ belongs to.

**I did it as follows:**

> Differentiating $x^3 = 12y$ wrt $y$,
> $$3x^2\frac{dx}{dy} = 12$$
> $$\implies \frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{12}{3x^2}\quad, x \not = 0$$
> $$\implies \frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{4}{x^2}\quad, x \not = 0$$
> Now $\frac{dx}{dy}$ must be greater than $1$ so that the rate of change of abscissa is greater than rate of change of ordinate. So,
> $$\dfrac{4}{x^2} > 1\quad, x \not =  0\implies \boxed{x \in (-2, 2) - \{0\}}$$
> which is correct according to our book.

**Whereas, my friend solved it as follows:**

> Differentiating $x^3 = 12y$ wrt $x$,
> $$\implies 3x^2 = 12 \dfrac{dy}{dx}$$
> $$\implies \dfrac{3 x^2}{12} = \dfrac{dy}{dx}$$
> $$\implies \dfrac{x^2}{4} = \dfrac{dy}{dx}$$
> Now, $\frac{dy}{dx}$ must be less than $1$ so that the abscissa changes at a faster rate than the ordinate. So,
> $$\frac{x^2}{4} < 1 \implies\boxed{ x \in (-2, 2)}$$

What's the mistake? Whose answer is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

For $$x^3 = 12y,$$ as $x$ or $y$ approaches $0,$ $\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}$ tends to $\infty$ while $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ tends to $0.$

Your friend's method is correct. On the other hand, your method utilises $\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy}$ but doesn't otherwise try to analyse the point $(0,0);$ so, it is incomplete.

To be clear: the given exercise doesn't intrinsically require $\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dy},$ or even $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx},$ to be defined at every point.

Comment: This is the best answer. But I just want to know, why does this restriction arise that $x \not = 0$ in my answer? What does that signify?

Comment: Because your method tries to find dx/dy, which does not exist at the point (0,0). That's not a problem, because the line y=3 has no dx/dy anywhere either...

Comment: Ohh okk. Thank you for answering my question. But I think I'm tend to believe on my calculations rather than graphical analysis. I'm sure if this type of question comes in my exam, I will definitely write my answer as $(-2, 2) - \{ 0\}$ following first method.

Comment: There is no need to draw graphs; that was just to illustrate my explanation; as I said, your answer is not invalid, just incomplete: after discovering that dx/dy doesn't exist at $0,$ you made a logical leap that this means that that point is somehow undefined or that what you require cannot be there; *this* leap is illogical, is all.

Comment: I think to be a normal calculus student, this is quite difficult for me to think in this manner every time. I always think that my task is done as soon as I approach an answer. :p

Comment: I mean, if I ask you for the interval on which y=3 has a gradient less than 7, and you decide to calculate dx/dy and find that it is undefined everywhere, do you then conclude that the required interval is non-existent? You shouldn't, because dx/dy being undefined is irrelevant. Better to keep making sense of and interpreting our results / sub-results. -)

Comment: Hmm. This answer is really very informative for me.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = t$, then the curve is the set of points
$$C = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | (x, y) = (t, t^3/12), t \in \mathbb{R}\}.$$
Then taking the derivative with respect to $t$ you get the vector $(1, t^2/4)$. This is the vector of the "rates of change" for abscissa and ordinate respectively. To find the region of the parameter where the first is larger than the second, we find
$$ 1 > t^2/4 \implies t \in (-2, 2).$$
Since $t=x$, this implies $x \in (-2, 2)$. Your method fails to find $x=0$ and I believe the book is incorrect. If you plot the curve it's clear that the curve is defined at $x=0$ and that the derivative at that point is zero, which is clearly less than one.

Answer (score -2):

The answers are equivalent: in your friend's answer he has to notice that if $x = 0$ then $y=0$. Hnece $dy/dx = 0$ which is not less than $1$ and so $x = 0$ is not a solution and has to be discarted.

The difference in the two approaches is that this requirement is apparent in your solution while it has to be noticed in your friend's answer.

Hope this helps.